# Access Jenkins build log within build script

Tags: jenkins, hudson

How would you go about accessing contents of the build (console) log from within a running build script?

I have a deploy script that runs, logs into a series of servers and runs scripts on those servers. I need to obtain certain output from some of those remote scripts and use them later in the build process and also in the completion email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in the Post Build section, but I don't think you can do it earlier in the job.  With the groovy post build plugin you can get information from the console log:

```
if(manager.logContains("text to find")) {
    do something
}
```